# Looping through python function arguments

Tags: python

I have a python function that receives many arguements. I want to change all the functions arguements to lowercase.
I have this code:

```
functionOne(para, paraa, parab):
    arguments = locals()
    print arguments
    for keys in arguments:
       arguments[keys] = str(arguments[keys]).lower()
       print arguments[keys]
    print para
```

With the output:

```
{'para':'HP', 'paraa':'MA', 'parab':'aM'}
hp
ma
am
HP
```

I would like para to equal hp not HP.

Comment: The para prints as 'HP' after the loop is done. Its value was not changed to lower case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to mess with `locals()`. If your function just has positional parameters, it shouldn't have too many, so you can change them one by one.

```
functionOne(para, paraa, parab):
    arguments = (para, paraa, parab)
    print arguments
    para, paraa, parab = map(str.lower, arguments)
    print para
```

If your function will have a larger, arbitrary number of arguments, use `*`:

```
functionOne(*args):
    print args
    args = tuple(map(str.lower, args))
    print args[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible.  Python's [`locals`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) don't modify the names in the function's namespace.  According to the docs:

> **Note** The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may<sup>1</sup> not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.

The only solution is to keep using `arguments` to access the values, or to lowercase each one by hand, or to pass an iterable of arguments rather than explicitly naming each one.

<sup><sup>1</sup>"may" is probably in there because implementations that aren't Cpython are free to implement `locals` differently.  A better wording might be "changes are not required to affect ..."</sup>

---

At a higher level, having a function with enough arguments that lowercasing "by hand" is cumbersome is a bit of a "code-smell" and might mean that a refactor is in order.

Comment: ok, is there no possible way to do it without using locals() but still looping?

Comment: @Rorschach -- Nope.  Not that I can think of.  Simply put, you can't modify the "local" namespace of a function like that.

Comment: You could pass the arguments as a list of strings, and then iterate through the list.  One parameter with several parts allows you to iterate.

Comment: @Prune -- Yep, definitely a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

```
para = para.lower()
paraa = paraa.lower()
parab = parab.lower()
```

The loop you wrote works on a constructed list, not the original arguments.  here's the full change:

```
def functionOne(para, paraa, parab):
    arguments = locals()
    print arguments
    for keys in arguments:
        arguments[keys] = str(arguments[keys]).lower()
        print arguments[keys]
    para = para.lower()
    paraa = paraa.lower()
    parab = parab.lower()
    print locals()

functionOne('HP', 'MA', 'aM')
```

Giving output:

```
{'parab': 'aM', 'paraa': 'MA', 'para': 'HP'}
am
ma
hp
{'keys': 'para', 'parab': 'am', 'paraa': 'ma', 'arguments': {...}, 'para': 'hp'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the return dictionary of locals() is undefined behavior. It won't do what you want. May I suggest using a decorator instead:

```
from functools import wraps
def lower_args(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        args = list(args)
        for i, a in enumerate(args):
            if isinstance(a, basestring):
                args[i] = a.lower()
        for key, val in kwargs.items():
            if isinstance(val, basestring):
                kwargs[key] = val.lower()
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@lower_args
def functionOne(para, paraa, parab):
    print para
```